# after_save callback of act_as_nested_set model lead to SystemStackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-5.1, nested-sets

I am using Rails 5.1.6

I have a model called `Taxon` using `acts_as_nested_set`. I have 4 levels of Taxons, the last level `sub_category` has an attribute holding names of all parents, I want to update the `sub_category` attribute every time any of its parents name is changed, when using `after_save` callback it runs into `SystemStackError` as each after save callback is run for each child leading to infinite loop. Any idea how to overcome this issue?

```
class Taxon
  acts_as_nested_set dependent: :destroy

  def update_tree_name
  if shop_sub_category?
    update(display_tree_name: beautiful_name)
  else 
    related_sub_categories = tree_list.select{ |taxon| taxon.kind == "sub_category" }
    related_sub_categories.each do |t|
      t.update(display_tree_name: t.beautiful_name)
    end
  end
end


def beautiful_name
  "#{parent.parent.parent.name} -> #{parent.parent.name} -> #{parent.name}-> #{name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that will work for you but I do not think it is an elegant one but here you go and then you can fine tune it:

In your model:

```
class Taxon < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  after_save :update_tree_name, :unless => :skip_callbacks
end

def update_tree_name
  if shop_sub_category?
    update(display_tree_name: beautiful_name)
  else 
    related_sub_categories = tree_list.select{ |taxon| taxon.kind == "sub_category" }
    Taxon.skip_callbacks = true # disable the after_save callback so that you do not end up in infinite loop (stackoverflow)
    related_sub_categories.each do |t|
      t.update(display_tree_name: t.beautiful_name)
    end
    Taxon.skip_callbacks = false # enable callbacks again when you finish
  end
end
```